# Statistical saturation attack on block ciphers

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, attack

I was wondering if anyone around here could give me some explanation on this type of attacks. Pretty much the only thing that I could find is [A Statistical Saturation Attack
against the Block Cipher PRESENT](http://www.uclouvain.be/crypto/services/download/publications.pdf.b348a292669d7d09.5353415f50726573656e742e706466.pdf).

What I really need is basic explanation of the attack itself with a small example if possible such as any basic block cipher that you could come up with with 3-4 rounds. This is for my personal understanding so any input is more than welcome.